# 'No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed' after using Boot-Repair no dual-boot

Tags: boot, 14.04, uefi

I just installed Ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64 on a desktop computer. I get

```
No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed
```

when booting.

The only way to boot Ubuntu is to go the BIOS menu and select
**Application UEFI ->  HDD -> EFI -> ubuntu**
where I have the files:

```
mockx64.efi
grubx64.efi
shimx64.efi
```

`shimx64.efi` allows me to boot Ubuntu.

I tried boot repairing from Ubuntu, but it didn't work [(here's the info link)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9023488/)

I also tried downloading the boot-repair ISO, but it doesn't do anything after the load screen when I boot it from the usb stick.

I did all of that following the answers in:

['No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed' after using Boot-Repair (Windows 8/Ubuntu dual-boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332041/no-boot-disk-has-been-detected-or-the-disk-has-failed-after-using-boot-repair)

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I just manually copied `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` to `/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` and it worked perfectly with Secure Boot off.

```
sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
```

Comment: What brand/model computer. Typical for HP & Sony. They modify UEFI to only boot UEFI entry with Windows in description. But will still boot hard drive which is boox64.efi. If you get a major grub update with a new grubx64.efi, you will have to copy it again.

Answer (score 0):

for Efi i solved by booting the flashdrive on ntfs(rufus) then the flash+resinstall process again.